# Is it possible to return a last deleted record id?

Tags: php, pdo

I want to create a method for my class that deleting one record, here is the source:

```
/* Delete One Record
 * in @param (string) $tbl - name of the table
 * in @param (int) $idn - id of record
 * @return (int) - identifier of removed record
 */
public function DelOne($tbl,(int)$idn)
{

    if ($result = $this->pdo->prepare("DELETE FROM `".$tbl."` WHERE `id`=:idn"))
    {

        $result->bindValue(":idn",$idn,PDO::PARAM_INT);

        $result->execute();

    }

}
```

And I want that this function returns me an identifier of just removed record instead of standart TRUE/FALSE combination.

Comment: Y can't you just return $idn ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Add `return $idn` in the function?

```
public function DelOne($tbl,(int)$idn)
{

    if ($result = $this->pdo->prepare("DELETE FROM `".$tbl."` WHERE `id`=:idn"))
    {

        $result->bindValue(":idn",$idn,PDO::PARAM_INT);

        // if all is well, return $idn
        if($result->execute()) return $idn;

    }

    // if we are here, something was wrong
    return false;

}
```

Comment: @VictorCzechov We all have that moments when we can't think of the simplest stuff x)

Comment: Ok, that is strange, but if the row with id = 2 doesn't exists anymore it's anyway returns me 2. So how to make it so that if the row wasn't deleted it's return me FALSE?

Comment: @VictorCzechov you could add a check using `SELECT COUNT() WHERE ID=`.

Comment: @SiGanteng after commenting on the question post, I was coding and before I could submit, you submitted. However, I deleted my answer (because that would be duplicate) :P LOL

Comment: @KarmicDice oooh ok, that makes more sense now x).

Comment: yeah, I mean if the row is not exists it's anyway returns me 2. So it's not a good solution I guess.

Comment: @VictorCzechov As far as I'm aware, PDO driver doesn't return the last deleted ID, so you gotta fetch it yourself. I agree that it would be better if they have a uniform way of fetching last deleted ID, until then, this is the best solution I could offer you (feel free to unaccept if you are not happy :)

Comment: @SiGanteng all is good! I am accepted. And the SELECT COUNT() a very good idea. Thanks you all!